# Allow access from regional HTTP API Gateway to private API gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are building a public-facing AWS HTTP API Gateway which integrates several existing VPC/private resources:

- EC2-based services
- internal APIs built on private AWS API gateways

The EC2-based resources are easily accessible to the public gateway via Load Balancers (ALBs) and Target Groups (TGs).

However, the private APIs are a different story. It seems they can't be integrated via direct URL, nor ALB...

It seems this is an unsupported architectural pattern. Which is... super weird.

Answer (score 1):

For REST API's, this pattern is definitely supported. I have designed, implemented, and had this architecture reviewed by two SA's at Amazon for accuracy and completeness. However for public or private HTTP API's (v2), I have not tested this personally but I believe the same pattern can be followed. The architecture diagram below illustrates how this works in the real world. It is very secure because your load balancers are no longer accessible publicly and is quite scalable.

[image: Distributed REST API Model]

The model above (from top of the workflow to the bottom) consists of:

- Route53 (pointing to API Gateway domain)
- WAF on top of API GW to prevent bots, etc..
- API Gateway + VPC Link
- Authorizer Lambda to check tokens and grant access to a given API/method
- Requests are then sent to a NLB with IP targets
- The IP targets are VPC Endpoints
- VPC Endpoint are connected to VPC Endpoint Services in the target account(s) (e.g. PrivateLink) and are not DNS enabled (in this case).
- The VPC Endpoint Service is an integration of a NLB.
- The NLB has a target type of ALB in the target account(s)
- The ALB target is the load balancer over the underlying service.

**NOTE:** Route53 and WAF are not needed with **private API's**.

With this model, the API Gateway lives in its dedicated account and requests are sent to target accounts. Full documentation of this Terraform/Terragrunt module can be found here. https://registry.terraform.io/modules/adamwshero/api-gateway/aws/latest

You can also read more about this concept overall in an AWS blog here.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-vpc-links-in-amazon-api-gateway-private-integrations/

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out this architecture actually is viable, although it requires a redundant private Network Load Balancer (NLB) handling the traffic to the private API Gateway...

The scheme of an inbound request is:

1. Public-facing API Gateway
2. VPC Link
3. Private NLB
4. Target Group targeting IPs of a VPC Endpoint of API Gateway type
5. API Gateway VPC Endpoint
6. Private API Gateway

The route must specify the targeted private API Gateway via the `x-apigw-api-id` HTTP header.